# Python AMD GPU monitoring

Tags: python, gpu, monitoring, psutil

I'm trying to make a GPU usage monitor, but I have an AMD GPU, so I had to use the pyadl library instead of some better for NVIDIA.
this is my code:

```py
from pyadl import *

device = ADLManager.getInstance().getDevices()[0]
print(device.getCurrentUsage())
```

and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\MSI_user\Documents\dev\Arduino\projects\pyArduino\passData-9.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(device.getCurrentUsage())
  File "C:\Users\MSI_user\Documents\dev\Arduino\projects\pyArduino\pyArd\lib\site-packages\pyadl\pyadl.py", line 293, in getCurrentUsage
    return ADLManager.getInstance().getCurrentUsage(self)
  File "C:\Users\MSI_user\Documents\dev\Arduino\projects\pyArduino\pyArd\lib\site-packages\pyadl\pyadl.py", line 182, in getCurrentUsage
    raise ADLError("Failed to get CurrentUsage")
pyadl.pyadl.ADLError: Failed to get CurrentUsage
```

I have researched quite a bit, but I don't have any idea how to fix it. Here is also the github link for the python lib - [pyadl](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
Maybe this lib is too old, but I haven't found any better for AMD GPUs. If you know any, please recommend.
Please help :D